# Reference ui from events with additional selector

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to do the following using Marionette:

```
events: {
    'mousedown @ui.timeRange:not(.disabled)': 'startSeeking'
},

ui: {
    timeRange: 'input.timeRange',
}
```

It doesn't work, but this does:

```
events: {
    'mousedown input.timeRange:not(.disabled)': 'startSeeking'
},

ui: {
    timeRange: 'input.timeRange',
}
```

Is there a way to re-use my ui reference while applying an additional filter after?

Comment: This is may not what you want, but why don't you check the element status in the startSeeking function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this usage is not the purpose of `ui`.

`ui` aims to give a quick and single reference to DOM elements. It would not be nice to manipulate `ui` again.

I would prefer such usage:

```
ui: {
  activeTimeRange: 'input.timeRange:not(.disabled)',
  disabledTimeRange: 'input.timeRange:(.disabled)'
},


events: {
  'mousedown @ui.activeTimeRanage': 'startSeeking'
}
```